# Intercalar valores en un lista

Tags: python, lista

Tengo una lista con valores

```
valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

que corresponden con unas coordenadas

```
coordenadas = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'y']
```

Quiero completar la lista de valores según una lista de coordenadas completa, rellenando los valores inexistentes con '-'.

```
coordenadas_completas = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

El resultado sería

```
valores_completos = [1, '-', '-', 2, 3, 4, '-', 5, '-']
```

Comment: ¿Siempre sigue la secuencia xxyzy o puede seguir otra diferente?

Comment: Puede ser cualquier secuencia.

Comment: Y si la secuencia dice `['x', 'y', 'y', 'z' ]` por ejemplo, ¿cómo sabes a si debes extraer las coordenadas (x,y,) (,y,) (,,z) o bien (x,,), (,y,), (,y,z) (o incluso otras variantes como (,,,), (x,y), (y,z), etc) ?

Comment: @abulafia, en este caso, con la secuencia `['x', 'y', 'y', 'z']` tendríamos las coordenadas (x, y) e (y, z). Se deberían rellenar los valores de z (para (x, y)) y x (para (y, z)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una posibilidad sería usar un generador cíclico infinito para obtener las coordenadas esperadas en cada posición e ir comparando con las que se tienen realmente:

```
import itertools


DIMENSIONES = "xyz"

valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
coordenadas = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'y']

coordenadas_esperadas = itertools.cycle(DIMENSIONES)
coordenadas_completas = []

for coordenada, valor in zip(coordenadas, valores):
    for coordenada_esperada in coordenadas_esperadas:
        if coordenada == coordenada_esperada:
            coordenadas_completas.append(valor)
            break
        coordenadas_completas.append("-")

coordenadas_completas.extend("-" * (len(DIMENSIONES) - DIMENSIONES.index(coordenada) - 1))

print(coordenadas_completas)
```

> ```
> [1, '-', '-', 2, 3, 4, '-', 5, '-']
> ```

Se usa `itertools.cycle` de la stdlib, aunque se podría implementar de forma simple el generador. El código funciona con cualquier número de "dimensiones", por ejemplo usando cuatro:

```
import itertools


DIMENSIONES = "xyzt"

valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
coordenadas = ['x', 't', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'y']

coordenadas_esperadas = itertools.cycle(DIMENSIONES)
coordenadas_completas = []
for coordenada, valor in zip(coordenadas, valores):
    for coordenada_esperada in coordenadas_esperadas:
        if coordenada == coordenada_esperada:
            coordenadas_completas.append(valor)
            break
        coordenadas_completas.append("-")
coordenadas_completas.extend("-" * (len(DIMENSIONES) - DIMENSIONES.index(coordenada) - 1))

print(coordenadas_completas)
```

> ```
> [1, '-', '-', 2, 3, 4, 5, '-', '-', 6, '-', '-']
> ```

Comment: Este código se adapta a cualquier tipo de lista de valores y coordenadas que obtenga en los resultados. Gracias @FJSevilla.

Answer (score 1):

Aporto solución generalizada a `n` dimensiones recursivamente en POO:

```
class valores():

    def rellena(self):
        k = self.i%len(self.secuencia)
        if self.secuencia[k]==self.coordenadas[self.j]:
            self.valores_completos.append(self.valores[self.j])
            self.i+=1
        else:
            self.valores_completos.append('-')
            self.i+=1
            self.rellena()

    def rectifica(self):
        self.valores_completos=[]
        self.i=0
        for self.j in range(len(self.valores)):
            self.rellena()

v=valores()
v.valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
v.coordenadas = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'y']
v.secuencia=['x','y','z','m','n']
v.rectifica();

print(v.valores_completos)
```

Y la amplío conforme a tus indicaciones:

```
class valores():

    def rellena(self):
        k = self.i%len(self.secuencia)
        if self.secuencia[k]==self.coordenadas[self.j]:
            self.valores_completos.append(self.valores[self.j])
            self.i+=1
        else:
            self.valores_completos.append('-')
            self.i+=1
            self.rellena()

    def rectifica(self):
        self.valores_completos=[]
        self.i=0
        for self.j in range(len(self.valores)):
            self.rellena()
        l_secuencia=len(self.secuencia)
        resto=len(self.valores_completos)%len(self.secuencia)
        if resto>0:
            for i in range(l_secuencia-resto):
                self.valores_completos.append('-')

v=valores()
v.valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
v.coordenadas = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'y']
v.secuencia=['x','y','z']
v.rectifica();

print(v.valores_completos)
```

Ahora sí que proporciona el resultado que esperas:

```
[1, '-', '-', 2, 3, 4, '-', 5, '-']
```

Espero que te resulte útil

Comment: Algo falla en el código. El resultado que obtengo es `[1, '-', '-', '-', '-', 2, 3, 4, '-', '-', '-', 5]` cuando debería ser `[1, '-', '-', '-', '-', 2, 3, 4, '-', '-', '-', 5, '-', '-', '-']`. `[1, '-', '-', '-', '-']` por el grupo de coordenadas `(x)`, `[2, 3, 4, '-', '-']` por el grupo de coordenadas `(x, y, z)` y `['-', 5, '-', '-', '-']` por el grupo de coordenadas `(y)`. En el último grupo de coordenadas no completa la secuencia.

Comment: Gracias por probarlo. Ten en cuenta que esta solución la he particularizado a 5 dimensiones en vez de a las 3 que tú usas. Quítale la `m` y la `n` a `v.secuencia` y obtendrás el resultado que esperas. En un rato amplío la respuesta para ilustrarla con ambos ejemplos

Comment: Está bien que hayas incluido 5 dimensiones. En mi caso real puedo tener, dependiendo de los resultados, desde 1 hasta 6 dimensiones.

Comment: Si elimino `m` y `n` de la secuencia obtengo `[1, '-', '-', 2, 3, 4, '-', 5]`, cuando debería ser `[1, '-', '-', 2, 3, 4, '-', 5, '-']`.

Comment: Ah, ya entiendo, que debería terminar la secuencia con todas las coordenadas... Ok, le doy una vuelta a ver qué se me ocurre y modifico la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Mi aporte:

Primero separamos en trozos que compondran las tripletas de coordenadas:

```
coordenadas = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'y']
valores = [10,20,30,40,50]
chunks = ''.join(coordenadas).replace('xx', 'x-x').replace('yx', 'y-x').replace('yy', 'y-y').replace('z', 'z-').strip('-').split('-')
chunks

['x', 'xyz', 'y']
```

Y luego simplemente comprobamos lo que tenemos en cada trozo, y lo que no lo dejamos como `-`:

```
valores_completos = []
count = 0
for chunk in chunks:
    valores_completos += ['-','-','-']
    if 'x' in chunk:
        valores_completos[-3] = valores[count]
        count += 1
    if 'y' in chunk:
        valores_completos[-2] = valores[count]
        count += 1
    if 'z' in chunk:
        valores_completos[-1] = valores[count]
        count += 1

valores_completos   

[10, '-', '-', 20, 30, 40, '-', 50, '-']
```

Con la ventaja de tener muy poquitos bucles y funciona para cualquier tamaño de lista de coordenadas :)

*Editado para que use los elementos de la lista valores

Comment: El código es bastante simple, aunque no resuelve mi problema real. Por simplicidad, en mi pregunta la lista de valores es una secuencia de números del 1 al 5. En realidad cada ítem de esta lista puede tener cualquier valor y no veo como introducirlos en el código.

Comment: Pensaba que la lista valores era meramente informativa... He editado mi respuesta y ahora ya coge los valores. Ha sido simplemente modificar `count` por `valores[count]` y empezar el conteo desde el indice 0. Easy peasey ;)

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo esta solución:

```
valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
coordenadas = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'y']

valores_completos=[]

secuencia=['x','y','z']

i=0
for j in range(len(valores)):
    if secuencia[i%3]==coordenadas[j]:
        valores_completos.append(valores[j])
        i+=1
    else:
        valores_completos.append('-')
        i+=1
        if secuencia[i%3]==coordenadas[j]:
            valores_completos.append(valores[j])
            i+=1
        else:
            valores_completos.append('-')
            i+=1        
            if secuencia[i%3]==coordenadas[j]:
                valores_completos.append(valores[j])
                i+=1
            else:
                valores_completos.append('-')
                i+=1


print(valores_completos)
```

Quedaría más elegante en un bucle para generalizarlo a `n` dimensiones, pero así parece que funciona. Lo he resuelto con un contador doble (`i`,`j`) y la operación módulo para calcular el resto de una división. Por favor, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para ampliar la respuesta lo mejor posible.